# I need help signing up for iTunes Match

Tags: itunes-match

I have an older Apple laptop and want to load iTunes match. When following the directions the "Match" tab, trying to "Enable iCloud Music Library" or any other reference to the path that I can sign up for the service is never presented.

What am I missing?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different Tom :) Kindly consider [editing](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/335348/edit) the question to specify the version of macOS and iTunes running on your Apple laptop. To view macOS version go to Apple Menu → About This Mac in the Menu Bar. To determine the version of iTunes, open iTunes app and go to iTunes → About iTunes in the Menu bar. This will help in getting quick and relevant answers.

Comment: “To subscribe to iTunes Match, you need iTunes 10.5.2 or later on your Mac or PC.” From [Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204146).

Answer (score 1):

The first thing is to check that your iTunes is new enough for the subscription service. You didn’t mention how old your OS is so if you need help figure I get that out, Apple offers presales support via phone and web chat.

I believe iTunes 10.5 is required, so try to update your Mac OS and then iTunes as far as you can to current.

Next, if you’re sure your iTunes is ok, it’s likely a payment or date/time error. Again, without some specific details we might struggle to help you out further.